# Clang-tidy incorrect rounding

Tags: c++, rounding, clang-tidy

The documentation for the clang-tidy [[bugprone-incorrect-roundings]](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/incorrect-roundings.html) check says:

> The number 0.499999975 (smallest representable float number below 0.5) rounds to 1.0

As far as I can detect the smallest float number below `0.5` is `0.4999999702`, not a `0.499999975`. But despite of this, both numbers [give me `0` values](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yU1tsJL6yIeFH5By) in naive rounding calculation:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   
    const float v1 = 0.499999975;
    const float v2 = 0.4999999702;

    std::cout << (int)(v1+0.5) << "\n" 
              << (int)(v2+0.5) << "\n";
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the arithmetic conversion in the standard:

> 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is double.
> - The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type;

So in this line:

```
(int)(v1+0.5)
```

Your `v1` variable is promoted to a double precision floating point operation, that's why you get zero.

This should fix your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    const float v1 = 0.499999975f;
    const float v2 = 0.4999999702f;

    std::cout << (int)(v1 + 0.5f) << "\n" 
              << (int)(v2 + 0.5f) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: But nobody is typing `+0.5f` even in clang-tidy example. Hence `+0.5` should works well, aint it?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ not quite. Double has enough bits to represent v1 + 0.5 0.99999975 which is truncated to zero by (int). But float has too few bits, so it rounds to 1.0, and later (int) truncates that to 1

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Also, note that this depends on the [rounding mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round). `std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);`  will make it always return 0, even for float

Comment: @MichaelVeksler code from documentation says `double_expression`, and since `0.5` is double too, I still can't see the problem with such rounding (for positive values).

Comment: In a double precision operation, the number 0.499999975 is not rounded to 0.5, so when you add 0.5, you get ~0.999999975. If you add 0.5f, the operation is performed in single precision, so the number 0.499999975f is rounded to 0.5f and then the result is 1.0f.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ The problem is with pure float values in this case. With double the values are slightly different: 0.499999999999999944, but the effect is the same. `(int)(0.499999999999999944 + 0.5)` is rounded to 1, subject to the rounding mode. [Try this out](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Um2qAmGTAej2y1VP)

Comment: @MichaelVeksler It seems that documentation should get rid from float types, and leave only the double to eliminate the confusion.